# After i upate my app from Rails 3.2.13 to 4.2 link_to stop working (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arguments, link-to, rails-3-upgrade

My app was running on Rails 3.2.13 and everything was OK. Once i tried to update to Rails 4.2 i managed to fix all issues and now i can't reslov the problem with **link_to**. Here is one example:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', {:controller=>'connect', :action=>'remove_from_cart', :id=> donation.id} %>
```

here is the error i am receiving **wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)**:

From what i manage to find is that i must provide only one param into the link, and if i update the example from above to:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', '/connect/remove_from_cart' + donation.id} %>
```

it will fix the problem, but i dont belive it is the right and very smart fix because i have lot of links across the application.

What might be the problem why link_to suddenly stop working afther the update?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', '/connect/remove_from_cart', donation_id: donation.id %>
```

You could clean it up a bit more by putting this in your routes file:

```
post '/connect/remove_from_cart/:donation_id', to: 'connect#remove_from_cart', as: :remove_from_cart
```

and using this code for your link

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', remove_from_cart_path(donation_id: donation.id), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, If i add the donation_id as a 3th param into the link_to it will add it as attribute id for the link, but not part of the href. If i add it as remove_from_cart_path(donation.id) the href will be ok. This is OK solution... as i mention i will need to update all my link_to links into the application. I thought there is some better solution

Comment: Good point. Updated answer. You could also interpolate the donation id into the second arg of the link_to if you really want, but I think it's cleaner this way.